# Return latest values for each month filling empty values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2017 I have a table that looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry106.png and I would like to get the amount of members at the end of each month, filling out the blank months with the data from the previous month.

So having this table

```
Create table #tempCenters (
    OperationId int identity (1,1) primary key,
    CenterId int,
    members int,
    Change_date date,
    Address varchar(100), --non relevant
    Sales float --non relevant
)
```

with this data

```
INSERT INTO #tempCenters VALUES 
(1, 100, '2020-02-20', 'non relevant column', 135135),
(1, 110, '2020-04-15', 'non relevant column', 231635),
(1, 130, '2020-04-25', 'non relevant column', 3565432),
(1, 180, '2020-09-01', 'non relevant column', 231651),
(2, 200, '2020-01-20', 'non relevant column', 321365),
(2, 106, '2020-03-20', 'non relevant column', 34534),
(2, 135, '2020-06-25', 'non relevant column', 3224),
(2, 154, '2020-06-20', 'non relevant column', 2453453)
```

I am expecting this result

```
CenterId, Members, EOM_Date 
1, 100, '2020-2-28'
1, 100, '2020-3-30'
1, 130, '2020-4-31'
1, 130, '2020-5-30'
1, 130, '2020-6-31'
1, 130, '2020-7-31'
1, 130, '2020-8-30'
1, 180, '2020-9-31'
2, 200, '2020-1-31'
2, 200, '2020-2-28'
2, 106, '2020-3-31'
2, 106, '2020-4-30'
2, 106, '2020-5-31'
2, 135, '2020-6-30'
```

And this is what I´ve got so far

```
SELECT 
    t.centerId, 
    EOMONTH(t.Change_date) as endOfMonthDate, 
    t.members
FROM #tempCenters t
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT 
        S.CenterId, 
        Year(S.Change_date) as dateYear, 
        Month(S.Change_date) as dateMonth, 
        Max(s.OperationId) as id
  FROM   #tempCenters S
  GROUP BY CenterId, Year(Change_date), Month(Change_date)
) A
ON A.id = t.OperationId
```

which returns the values per month, but not fill the blank ones.

Comment: Hint `LAG`.....

Comment: There are some typos in column EOM_Date of the result.
It would be curious to see solution with using the LAG function.

Comment: @DaleK sorry, I forgotten what I´ve tried, now updated. I´ve tried with LAG with no success, I don´t know how to implement it properly

Comment: @DaleK sorry, I´ve tried with LAG with no success, I don´t know how to implement it properly, can you please share how could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I get start date (min date) and finish date (max date) for each CenterId. Then I generate all end of months from start date to finish date for each CenterId. Finally I join my subuqery (cte) with your table (on `cte.CenterId = tc.CenterId AND cte.EOM_Date >= tc.Change_date`) and get last (previous or same date) members value for each date (end of month).

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT CenterId, EOMONTH(MIN(Change_date)) AS EOM_Date, EOMONTH(MAX(Change_date)) AS finish
             FROM #tempCenters
             GROUP BY CenterId
             
             UNION ALL 
             
             SELECT CenterId, EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, EOM_Date)), finish
             FROM cte
             WHERE EOM_Date < finish)
             
             
SELECT DISTINCT cte.CenterId, 
       FIRST_VALUE(Members) OVER(PARTITION BY cte.CenterId, cte.EOM_Date ORDER BY tc.Change_date DESC) AS Members, 
       cte.EOM_Date 
FROM cte 
LEFT JOIN #tempCenters tc ON cte.CenterId = tc.CenterId AND cte.EOM_Date >= tc.Change_date
ORDER BY CenterId, EOM_Date;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @nachospiu but I´m getting this error when running it.

`The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`

I tested your solution and works fine with small amount of data, but I have a huge amount of records

Comment: You are welcome @Renom!!!! You can specify the [maxrecursion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) option at the end of the query (`option (maxrecursion 0)`), or You can set start and finish date to restrict your query.

Answer (score 0):

I know it looks cumbersome and I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but still you can use a combination of subqueries with union all and outer apply to get the desired result.

```
Select t.CenterId, Coalesce(t.members, tt.members), t.Change_date
From (
Select CenterId, Max(members) As members, Change_date
From
(Select t.CenterId, t.members, EOMONTH(t.Change_date) As Change_date
From #tempCenters As t Inner Join 
(Select CenterId, Max(Change_date) As Change_date
From #tempCenters 
Group by CenterId, Year(Change_date), Month(Change_date)
) As tt On (t.CenterId=tt.CenterId And
            t.Change_date=tt.Change_date)
Union All
Select t.CenterId, Null As member, t.Change_date
From (
Select tt.CenterId, EOMONTH(datefromparts(tt.[YEAR], t.[MONTH], '1')) As Change_date,
       Min_Change_date, Max_Change_date
From (Select [value] as [Month] From OPENJSON('[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]')) As t, 
                                    (Select CenterId, Year(Change_date) As [YEAR], 
                                            Min(Change_date) As Min_Change_date, Max(Change_date) As Max_Change_date
                                     From #tempCenters Group by CenterId, Year(Change_date)) As tt) As t
Where Change_date Between Min_Change_date And Max_Change_date) As t
Group by CenterId, Change_date) As t Outer Apply 
(Select members 
From #tempCenters 
Where CenterId=t.CenterId And
      Change_date = (Select Max(Change_date) 
                     From #tempCenters Where CenterId=t.CenterId And Change_date<t.Change_date Group by CenterId)) As tt
Order by t.CenterId, t.Change_date
```